# How to create test events in Tosca

Tags: testing, tosca

I have test cases and want to run in CMD. For this I need to have a configuration xml file.
I want to create test event in Tosca commander. But am not finding the option.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different things here.
First - Executing Test Cases from CMD. That is completly possible and for this you need to configure TOSCA CI, Where can specify which execution lists you want to execute along with TOSCA Repo details (including credentials & result file path).
Look out for sample command which can do this:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\TRICENTIS\Tosca Testsuite\ToscaCI\Client\ToscaCIClient.exe" -m local  -t junit -r "P:\1.0 TOSCA Data\Result.xml**

(where -m  parameter u need to specify what kind of execution it is, Local or DEX, -t parameter specifies type of reporting, As of today only Junit is supported, finally -r is location where execution report xml file will be stored)

Second point you mentioned about Test Events, Be clear on that, they are used only in case you have Distribution execution setup in place.

If you have any more specific question on this, put it clearly.